# RegEx help - find substring except when in specific word(s)

Tags: regex, ssms

A colleague is scanning a large script looking for the substring UAT (case insensitive). Unfortunately, the script contains many references to "valuation", either as a whole word or as part of a field name.

What RegEx search pattern would return matches for UAT as in the following samples?

- UAT : Match
- uat : Match
- TheUATServer1 : Match
- Valuation : No match
- ValuationDate: No match

Many thanks

Neil

Comment: Are there other words expected, besides `valuation`, that could lead to false positives? Say, `equate`?

Comment: Quite possibly, but it is "valuation" that is slowing things down at the moment. I presume I can OR conditions together to exclude multiple words if any others surfaced as a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This one works for the OP's cases.

Try this expression:  `uat~(ion)`

The SSMS (and Visual Studio) regex has different syntax for negative lookahead: `~(prevent)`

If you wanted `uat` by itself, you can use this: `<uat>`.

The `<` and `>` stand for begining and end of word, respectively.

Comment: This won't match `TheUATServer1` though -- which it should (cf. question).

Comment: @mhyfritz, of course you are right.  The new answer should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgrep -i "uat" FILE | fgrep -i -v "valuation"
```

Sometimes the simplest tools can do amazing things.

But you did not specify the tools you have, the regex flavor (there are many). And what you are searching for can be defined via regex (negative look-`(ahead|behind)`), but simple string search and negation can be faster.

Comment: the tools is SQL Server Management Studio (2008) via its Regular Expression search dialog. Am looking out fgrep now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
UAT(?!ion)
```

This is a negative lookahead, that ensures that `UAT` is not followed by `ion` like in `valuation`. I don't know if your tool is supporting this and if this rule is strict enough for your needs.

What you should activate is a case insensitive match.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED to be case insensitive and incorporate new requirement**

I think the regex you want is simply:

```
[Uu][aA][tT](?![iI][oO][nN])
```

ie `uat` (any case) not followed by `ion` (any case)